Why does a .jpg file change to .jpeg when dragging from my SwiftUI view to Finder folders
I'm working on a macOS app where I allow users to drag files from my app (a SwiftUI view) to Finder folders.
However, I've noticed that when I drag a .jpg file from my app to Finder, the file ends up being saved as a .jpeg instead of retaining the original .jpg extension.
Why?
.onDrag { 
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: file.path) { 
    // Provide the file as an item for dragging
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: file.path)
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(contentsOf: fileURL)                
    
    // Remove the file extension in the suggestedName
    let baseNameWithoutExtension = fileURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    itemProvider?.suggestedName = baseNameWithoutExtension
    
    return itemProvider ?? NSItemProvider()
} else {
    // Handle the case where the file no longer exists
    print("File no longer exists at path: \(file.path)")
    return NSItemProvider()
}
}


I'm no Swift expert, but you seem to be explicitly removing the original extension when you set the suggestedName. What happens if you don't do that?
